# Two definitions of Lebesgue covering dimension

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

Maybe this question has already been considered here, but after a quick search I  didn't find what I was looking for.

As I see, in the literature there are two different definitions of the topological/Lebegue covering dimension.

$\textbf{Definition 1.}$ (e.g. Munkres, General topology) A topological space $X$ is said to have the Lebesgue covering dimension $d<\infty$ if $d$ is the smallest non-negative integer with the property that each open cover of $X$ has a refinement in which no point of $X$ is included in more than $d+1$ elements.

$\textbf{Definition 2.}$  (e.g. Engelking, Ryszard, "Dimension theory" or Pears,
 "Dimension theory of general spaces") A topological space $X$ is said to have the Lebesgue covering dimension $d<\infty$ if $d$ is the smallest non-negative integer with the property that each $\textbf{finite}$ open cover of $X$ has a refinement in which no point of $X$ is included in more than $d+1$ elements.

Obviously these two definitions agree for compact spaces, but I suppose the first one is stronger in general. For which other class(es) of spaces these two definitions coincide (and for which they don't?

Also, I didn't find much results in the literature about "dimension theory" with respect to Definition 1. (Reference?) For example, is the analogue of the Subset theorem (Pears, Theorem 3.6.4) true when dealing with Definition 1 (i.e. If $S$ is a subset of a totally normal space $X$, then $\dim S \leq \dim X$)?

Comment: Side question: is there a (Hausdorff if possible) space that is of dimension 0 in Definition 2 but not Definition 1 (i.e., in which every finite open covering has a disjoint open refinement, but not every open covering does)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you refer to Engelking's "Dimension theory" book, I suppose you know the following two statements, but anyway, here they are:

- The notions agree for separable metric spaces, by Exercise 1.7.E of Engelking's book.
- The notions agree for paracompact spaces by Proposition 3.2.2 of Engelking's book. (In particular, if both dimensions are finite, they agree.)

An example where the two notions differ was suggested in the comment of Benoît Kloeckner: the long ray $[0,\omega_1)\times[0,1)$ with the lexicographic order topology. The long ray is locally compact but not paracompact. If we use the definition of covering dimension with arbitrary open covers, the long ray has infinite covering dimension (because finite covering dimension implies paracompactness). However, for the finitary covering dimension we get 1 as follows. Any *finite* open cover is essentially a couple of initial segments $((\lambda_1,a_i),(\lambda_2,b_i))$ with $\lambda_i$ countable ordinals and at least one long end $((\lambda,a),(\omega_1,1))$. The segments with the countable ordinals in the upper bound are homeomorphic to intervals $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. For the initial segments, we get a refinement such that at most two-fold intersections are nonempty (as one would do in $\mathbb{R}$), and only the last of the initial segments intersects the long end  $((\lambda,a),(\omega_1,1))$.

Addendum: I just noted that $[0,\omega_1)$ with the order topology is an even simpler (and slightly more puzzling) example. It is locally compact, Hausdorff and not paracompact, but its finitary covering dimension is $0$.

Comment: Thanks! I would be interested to see an example of a locally compact Hausdorff space (if such exists) for which these two notions fail to agree.

Comment: @Glimm: I would have a look to the *long ray*, but I do not have an argument (yet?).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: the long line seems to work. It should have infinite covering dimension if we use all coverings, but for finite coverings it seems one could reduce to a couple of initial segments and one covering set for the uncountably long rest - then it would seem that the finitary covering dimension would be 1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the long ray $R$ works. If $\mathcal{U}$ is a finite open cover then $\bigcap\{R\setminus U:U\in\mathcal{U}\}=\emptyset$ and at least one of these closed sets must be bounded as in $R$ any two closed ubbounded sets have closed unbounded intersection.
Fix one $V\in\mathcal{U}$ and an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $[\alpha,\omega_1)\subset V$ and refine the restriction of $\mathcal{U}$ to $[0,\alpha+1]$ to a cover of order $1$.

Comment: Since your answer is very closely related to a previous one, it would be helpful to indicate how does it differ

Comment: Judging by the timings of the answers and comments the question whether the long ray is an example seemed still open. Plus: there is a justification for the claim in the other answer about the form of a finite open cover of the long ray.